# Find gateway public IP in a sub network

Tags: linux, networking

How can I retrieve the public IP (as known from the Internet) of the gateway of my sub network ?

Is there a dedicated command for this purpose ?

I would like to perform this lookup from a machine of my sub network.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these will work:

```
lynx --dump http://ipecho.net/plain
```

Or:

```
curl http://ipecho.net/plain; echo
```

Or:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

This will give you the IP that the world sees when you browse the Internet.

Comment: Ask the Internet to do the job for you, clever!